# PullRefreshTableView editing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a PullRefreshTableView from leah(https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh). Problem with this, as soon as I implement this. The view is changed to a tableview by doing this:

```
@interface news : PullRefreshTableViewController {
```

So I can't add any toolbars or navigationcontrollers to the top. Does someone know how I can add a toolbar to the top of the screen in combination with the PullRefreshTableView.

Thnx!

Comment: Do you want to have the toolbar -in- your tableView, or on top of it? cause if you want the second choice, you can make a containerview and add both the toolbar and tableview as subviews. but i'm just asking and suggesting here :)

Comment: Sounds logical... and I understand the idea. But how can I implement something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know when you have this standard UINavigation template when you create a new project with xcode? Gives you 3 ( right ? ) nib files, 1 with the window, 1 with the mainview / navigation controller and the other one contains the tableview.

Open the one with the tableview. Select the tab that looks like this: [image: toolbar_item]
It will allow you to change the class it creates when the nib file is loaded. Change it to the PullRefreshTableView and when you launch the application a PullRefreshTableView will be created instead of a normal table view.

You can hook this up as an Interface Builder outlet exactly the same way you would hook up a normal table view. Its a subclass so it should even be able to be connected to the normal tableviewcontroller that is included in the template.

If you have done this, you should still be able to add the toolbars like you did with a normal table view. Also, if you want to have a toolbar on your iphone screen it shouldn't be a subview of the Tableview, but a container view should contain both the toolbar and the tableview.

Comment: I get the idea of not placing the toolbar within the table but put it in a container with the table view. But i'm not totally getting how to implement this. I tried to set the class of the NIB file to PullRefreshTableViewController, but for some reason in changes back to the original state again and again...

Comment: @Jos Log the outlet in the class that holds the tableview.. NSLog(@"%@",tableViewOutlet); this way you will find out what the actual type is and whether a PullRefreshTableView had been created or not

Comment: I think i'm not getting it really... Just to be clear: I don't have any xib file with an tableview in it, I do have a class which displays the table view, the superclass of this class is PullRefreshTableViewController. As soon as I change the superclass to i.e. UIViewController the tableview disappears. This seems logical, but I can't seem to find another way to implement the pullrefreshtrableviewcontroller. Thnx for the big effort!

Comment: @Jos have been afk for a while, so late response. Ehm the PullRefreshTableView is a subclass of UITableView. The logical thing would be to subclass UITableViewController to implemen the pullrefreshtableviewcontroller stuff, you can still connect the -tableView outlet of the tableviewcontroller to the pullrefreshtableview as they are of the same type. For instance any subclass of NSObject can be set in the pointer: NSObject *someObject;